# Dont I Have SCAS or CMPS in emu8086?

Tags: string, assembly, instructions

I write a short function  which need this instruction.
Dont I have these in EMU8086?

Comment: Should work, assembler syntax may be different. Try scasb or scasw.

Answer (score 2):

For `SCAS`,

Use [SCAWSB](http://www.itipacinotti.gov.it/pagine/sistemi2008/documentation_emulator/8086_instruction_set.html#SCASB) or [SCASW](http://www.itipacinotti.gov.it/pagine/sistemi2008/documentation_emulator/8086_instruction_set.html#SCASW). The `B` instruction compares bytes; the `W` instruction compares words.

For `CMPS`,

Use [CMPSB](http://www.itipacinotti.gov.it/pagine/sistemi2008/documentation_emulator/8086_instruction_set.html#CMPSB) or [CMPSW](http://www.itipacinotti.gov.it/pagine/sistemi2008/documentation_emulator/8086_instruction_set.html#CMPSW). Same thing: `B` version for bytes; `W` version for words.